# need .htaccess RewriteRule advise

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've looked around for an answer to this, no luck.

What i want to do is replace

`http://localhost/mysite/superv/something` with

`http://localhost/mysite/superv/?p=something`

Here's the best formula I came up with since yesterday:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^(superv/)([^\?/]+)$ $1\?p=$2 [NC]
```

Yet it's not working.

I think the "RewriteBase" thingy has nothing to do with the problem because this line is working like a charm:

`RewriteRule ^(javascripts/main\.js)$ $1\.php [NC]`

*Edit: Right Rekire, that was a mistake while copying and pasting the code. I've fixed the question now.*

*Edit2: Here's the error that appears in apache logs:*

```
 [Tue Mar 20 20:26:01 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] 
 Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
 Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I'm guessing the problem is "looping" and I quote:

```
 Looping occurs when the target of a rewrite rule matches the pattern. 
 This results in an infinite loop of rewrites
```

Comment: Well that cannot work if you write into your `RewriteRule` "superv" but you are trying to handele an URL with "admin".

Comment: Please note that the commentators won't be informed about edits. I'm wondering about that you are trying to redirect the user to a path instat of a php file. This could be your problem.

Comment: Don't escape characters in the replacement strings, e.g. `$1?p=$2`. Also why are you [internally] redirecting `http://localhost/mysite/javascripts/main.js` to `http://localhost/mysite/javascripts/main.js.php`?

Comment: I tried not escaping characters Terry, it didn't work either, I'm getting "500 Internal Server Error" with the same "Request exceeded the limit" log message.

I'm using the .js to .js.php redirect because I'm generating javascript code via php and don't want users to notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, this formula worked (internal redirect):

```
RewriteRule (.*)(superv/)?(.*) $1$2index.php?p=$3 [NC,QSA]
```

It seems to have broken the "infinite loop".

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be working for me.

```
RewriteRule ^(superv/)([^\?/]+)$ $1?p=$2 [R,NC]
```

Remove the R, if you want to do an internal redirect.

Comment: Hi, your line works, but once I remove the R I get the same "500 internal server error" and "Request exceeded the limit" error.